# Assign values as keys within loop

Tags: python

I'm trying to extract some information from a webpage where I am trying to extract links from it but I want to denote specifically the country it's from, which is available to me from another dataset.

For example:

```
links_countries = pd.DataFrame({'links': {0: 'https://www.transfermarkt.co.uk/spieler-statistik/wertvollstespieler/marktwertetop/plus/0/galerie/0?ausrichtung=alle&spielerposition_id=alle&altersklasse=alle&jahrgang=0&land_id=1&kontinent_id=0&yt0=Show',
  1: 'https://www.transfermarkt.co.uk/spieler-statistik/wertvollstespieler/marktwertetop/plus/0/galerie/0?ausrichtung=alle&spielerposition_id=alle&altersklasse=alle&jahrgang=0&land_id=2&kontinent_id=0&yt0=Show',
  2: 'https://www.transfermarkt.co.uk/spieler-statistik/wertvollstespieler/marktwertetop/plus/0/galerie/0?ausrichtung=alle&spielerposition_id=alle&altersklasse=alle&jahrgang=0&land_id=3&kontinent_id=0&yt0=Show'},
 'countries': {0: 'Afghanistan', 1: 'Albania', 2: 'Algeria'}})

final_data=[]
for m in range(0, 3):
    df = {}
    driver.get(links_countries['links'][m])
    time.sleep(3)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html5lib')
    pages = soup.select("#yw2 a")
    pag = []
    for p in pages:
        pag.append(p.get_text(strip=True).replace('', ''))
    pag = [string for string in pag if string != ""]
    pag = int(pag[-1])
    print('Page number', pag)
    href = []
    for t in pages:
        href.append(t['href'])
    href = [string for string in href if string != ""]
    urls = "https://www.transfermarkt.co.uk" + href[0]
    
    for num in range(1, pag+1):
        url = urls + str(num)
        print(url)
        driver.get(url)
        time.sleep(3)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html5lib')
        links = soup.find('table', {'class':'items'}).find_all("a")
        for li in links:
            for name in links_countries['countries']:
                df[name].append(li['href'].replace("#", ''))   <------   #code fails here
    final_data.append(df)
```

I get the following error:

```
KeyError: 'Afghanistan'
```

Expected outcome:

```
                                            Afghanistan           player_names
 0   https://www.transfermarkt.co.uk/rahmat-akbari/...          rahmat-akbari
 1   https://www.transfermarkt.co.uk/omran-haydary/...          omran-haydary
 2   https://www.transfermarkt.co.uk/mustafa-azadzo...        mustafa-azadzoy
 3   https://www.transfermarkt.co.uk/farshad-noor/p...           farshad-noor
 4   https://www.transfermarkt.co.uk/zohib-islam-am...      zohib-islam-amiri
 5   https://www.transfermarkt.co.uk/hassan-amin/pr...            hassan-amin
..
..
..
                                           Albania               Player names
..
..
```

Output after answers:

```
Afghanistan Albania Algeria Andorra Angola  Anguilla    Argentina   Armenia Aruba   Australia   ... Vietnam Wales   Yemen   Zaire   Zambia  Zanzibar    Zimbabwe    All 
0   [, , /rahmat-akbari/profil/spieler/543320, /ra...   [, , /rahmat-akbari/profil/spieler/543320, /ra...   [, , /rahmat-akbari/profil/spieler/543320, /ra...   [, , /rahmat-akbari/profil/spieler/543320, /ra...   [, , /rahmat-akbari/profil/spieler/543320, /ra...   [, , /rahmat-akbari/profil/spieler/543320, /ra...   [, , /rahmat-akbari/profil/spieler/543320, /ra...   [, , /rahmat-akbari/profil/spieler/543320, /ra...   [, , /rahmat-akbari/profil/spieler/543320, /ra...   [, , /rahmat-akbari/profil/spieler/543320, /ra...   ... [, /rahmat-akbari/profil/spieler/543320, /bris...   [, /rahmat-akbari/profil/spieler/543320, /bris...   [, /rahmat-akbari/profil/spieler/543320, /bris...   [, /rahmat-akbari/profil/spieler/543320, /bris...   [, /rahmat-akbari/profil/spieler/543320, /bris...   [, /rahmat-akbari/profil/spieler/543320, /bris...   [, /rahmat-akbari/profil/spieler/543320, /bris...   [, /rahmat-akbari/profil/spieler/543320, /bris...   NaN NaN
1   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN ... NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 0 https://www.transfermarkt.co.uk/mohamed...    0 mohamed-salah 1 mohamed-elneny ...
2   [, , /rahmat-akbari/profil/spieler/543320, /ra...   [, , /rahmat-akbari/profil/spieler/543320, /ra...   [, , /rahmat-akbari/profil/spieler/543320, /ra...   [, , /rahmat-akbari/profil/spieler/543320, /ra...   [, , /rahmat-akbari/profil/spieler/543320, /ra...   [, , /rahmat-akbari/profil/spieler/543320, /ra...   [, , /rahmat-akbari/profil/spieler/543320, /ra...   [, , /rahmat-akbari/profil/spieler/543320, /ra...   [, , /rahmat-akbari/profil/spieler/543320, /ra...   [, , /rahmat-akbari/profil/spieler/543320, /ra...   ... [, /rahmat-akbari/profil/spieler/543320, /bris...   [, /rahmat-akbari/profil/spieler/543320, /bris...   [, /rahmat-akbari/profil/spieler/543320, /bris...   [, /rahmat-akbari/profil/spieler/543320, /bris...   [, /rahmat-akbari/profil/spieler/543320, /bris...   [, /rahmat-akbari/profil/spieler/543320, /bris...   [, /rahmat-akbari/profil/spieler/543320, /bris...   [, /rahmat-akbari/profil/spieler/543320, /bris...   NaN NaN
3   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN ... NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 0 https://www.transfermarkt.co.uk/mohamed...    0 mohamed-salah 1 mohamed-elneny ...
4   [, , /rahmat-akbari/profil/spieler/543320, /ra...   [, , /rahmat-akbari/profil/spieler/543320, /ra...   [, , /rahmat-akbari/profil/spieler/543320, /ra...   [, , /rahmat-akbari/profil/spieler/543320, /ra...   [, , /rahmat-akbari/profil/spieler/543320, /ra...   [, , /rahmat-akbari/profil/spieler/543320, /ra...   [, , /rahmat-akbari/profil/spieler/543320, /ra...   [, , /rahmat-akbari/profil/spieler/543320, /ra...   [, , /rahmat-akbari/profil/spieler/543320, /ra...   [, , /rahmat-akbari/profil/spieler/543320, /ra...   ... [, /rahmat-akbari/profil/spieler/543320, /bris...   [, /rahmat-akbari/profil/spieler/543320, /bris...   [, /rahmat-akbari/profil/spieler/543320, /bris...   [, /rahmat-akbari/profil/spieler/543320, /bris...   [, /rahmat-akbari/profil/spieler/543320, /bris...   [, /rahmat-akbari/profil/spieler/543320, /bris...   [, /rahmat-akbari/profil/spieler/543320, /bris...   [, /rahmat-akbari/profil/spieler/543320, /bris...   NaN NaN
5   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you have `'links': {0: 'A', 1: 'B', 3: 'C'}` instead of `'links': ['A', 'B', C']`? It's just a list of links, what's the point of using a dict?

Comment: @Tomalak It's just the pd.to_dict() print out as it was originally a pandas dataframe. so this was the obvious choice to share my data

Comment: Ahh, I see. Still bit of a round-about way of storing the data. Maybe you can simplify that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for failure sould be you have initialised `df={}` and adding entry into it as `df[name]` and hence it says the `key` `name` does not exists. What you can do is:

```
df = defaultdict(list)
```

before your `for m in range(0, 3):` loop. Try out below code which contains the modifications:

```
from collections import defaultdict
links_countries = pd.DataFrame({'links': {0: 'https://www.transfermarkt.co.uk/spieler-statistik/wertvollstespieler/marktwertetop/plus/0/galerie/0?ausrichtung=alle&spielerposition_id=alle&altersklasse=alle&jahrgang=0&land_id=1&kontinent_id=0&yt0=Show',
  1: 'https://www.transfermarkt.co.uk/spieler-statistik/wertvollstespieler/marktwertetop/plus/0/galerie/0?ausrichtung=alle&spielerposition_id=alle&altersklasse=alle&jahrgang=0&land_id=2&kontinent_id=0&yt0=Show',
  2: 'https://www.transfermarkt.co.uk/spieler-statistik/wertvollstespieler/marktwertetop/plus/0/galerie/0?ausrichtung=alle&spielerposition_id=alle&altersklasse=alle&jahrgang=0&land_id=3&kontinent_id=0&yt0=Show'},
 'countries': {0: 'Afghanistan', 1: 'Albania', 2: 'Algeria'}})

final_data=[]
df = defaultdict(list)
for m in range(0, 3):
    driver.get(links_countries['links'][m])
    time.sleep(3)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html5lib')
    pages = soup.select("#yw2 a")
    pag = []
    for p in pages:
        pag.append(p.get_text(strip=True).replace('', ''))
    pag = [string for string in pag if string != ""]
    pag = int(pag[-1])
    print('Page number', pag)
    href = []
    for t in pages:
        href.append(t['href'])
    href = [string for string in href if string != ""]
    urls = "https://www.transfermarkt.co.uk" + href[0]
    
    for num in range(1, pag+1):
        url = urls + str(num)
        print(url)
        driver.get(url)
        time.sleep(3)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html5lib')
        links = soup.find('table', {'class':'items'}).find_all("a")
        for li in links:
            for name in links_countries['countries']:
                df[name].append(li['href'].replace("#", ''))   <------   #code fails here
    final_data.append(df)
```

Comment: Ah! Had a feeling I was missing something so simple ... I assigned ```df[name] = list()``` within the loop instead. But I'll probably practice you're approach as it saves headache early on.

Comment: I have a question: Whilst it helps the loops work, when I create a pandas dataframe from my list it gives the same values across all the countries, rather than each country given their respective size of links. Why is that?

Comment: Can you paste `final_data`?

Comment: I have uploaded it in the question. My dataset has more countries than what I posted here. But I used the same range ```range(0, 3)``` to see if it'd work on three of them. It should have also produced 3 countries with 2 links for the first and 10 each for the other 2. But it combines them all instead

Comment: This looks like a logical issue in your code, however the original issue is solved so maybe you can paste this as a another query on SO.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are iterating through a dictionary and not a list, you need to change the for loop like so

```
for key, value in links_countries['countries'].items():
    df[value].append(li['href'].replace("#", ''))
```

More on iterating through dictionaries here: https://realpython.com/iterate-through-dictionary-python/

Comment: Thanks for sharing this! I had tried something similar but did not append ```.items()``` at the end, which explains why it did not work.

Comment: Glad to help. I'd appreciate an upvote or accept on the answer if it was useful to you